# Upgrade to Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-2003, exchange-2010

We have a customer running Exchange 2003. They would like to upgrade.

Is there any reason to Upgrade to 2007 instead of going directly to 2010? For example are there any stability problems with 2010.

What would you recommend?

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been running Exchange 2010 since beta and I've had no problems at all with stability and I think it has some really nice improvements on 2007. That said it's only been released a month or so, and many people often like to wait till the 1st service pack to ensure all the bugs are worked out.

One thing to bear in mind is that you can't just upgrade from 2003 to 2007, or from 2007 to 2010, so if you did go to 2007 and then 2010, you would need to do 2 migrations.